# Use goquery to find a class whose value contains whitespace

Tags: go, html-parsing, goquery

*Answered*. User [PuerkitoBio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1094941/puerkitobio) helped me out with his `goquery` package, and I'm sure I won't be the only one wondering how to do this. *(I can mark this question as 'answered' in two days)*

When using `goquery` to find classes of html tags, I hit a problem when the class contains whitespace. Here's an example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    html_code := strings.NewReader(`
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>
            <span class="text title">Go </span>
        </h1>
        <p>
            <span class="text">totally </span>
            <span class="post">kicks </span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <span class="text">hacks </span>
        </p>
    </body>
<html>
    `)
    doc, _ := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(html_code)
}
```

If I want to find the class `"text title"`, I thought I would do this:

```
doc.Find(".text title").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
    class, _ := s.Attr("class")
    fmt.Println(class, s.Text())
})
```

But this doesn't work. *(Answer is below.)*

Comment: Oops. Thanks for the head's up!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It was a problem with my understanding of HTML. The whitespace inside `class="text title"` shows that `class` has two values: `text` and `title`. In order to find multiple attributes of a class with `goquery`, I need to put them side by side (without whitespace) and prefix them with a `.`. Like this:

```
doc.Find(".text.title").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
    class, _ := s.Attr("class")
    fmt.Println(class, s.Text())
})
```

Or if I ever want to find **only** the classes with the value `title`, I would do this:

```
doc.Find(".title").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
    class, _ := s.Attr("class")
    fmt.Println(class, s.Text())
})
```